# Feed URI to imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, image, uri, gd

I was wondering if there was any way to scale a data URI with only one file write:

From an AJAX uploaded image, I get the URI `$img`:

```
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
```

From here, I now have the decoded string. At this point, I can write it to a file, and then use `imagecreatefromjpeg` to scale it.

I'm looking for a way to skip this write operation, but `imagecreatefromjpeg` requires a filename input.

Any suggestions? Or should I just write the tmp file?

Answer (score 0):

```
imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

Also detects image type... userful!